# Is it possible to make large waves from perfectly timed single drops of water?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, waves, water, interference

Assume I have a hemispherical container of water and an eyedropper. Is it possible to add water to the container one drop at a time, such that each drop continues to add kinetic energy to the water?

When a water drop is added, it creates waves. I am wondering if it is possible to keep adding water drops in time with the waves, so that it acts like constructive interference, and adds more energy into the waves.

I think this could be a very interesting sculpture, to have a computer-controlled eyedropper which slowly builds up the amplitude of the waves.

Comment: Related: [Wave tank spike](https://youtu.be/iWKFPTgkpXo?t=94) from small, slight movements. But water drop dispensing is more dissipative and somewhat more random.

Answer (score 0):

For conservation of energy, you can't get more energy into the waves per drop than the loss of the gravitational potential energy of each drop.  Constructive and destructive interference only changes the distribution of the energy in the waves, not the total amount of wave energy.

At the same time energy is added to the waves by the drops, energy is dissipated in the waves due to the viscosity of water (viscous friction) and skin friction (drag) between the water and the surfaces of the container.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given water with no side boundaries, a drop of water generates ripples that spread out. The ripples carry energy. So the energy flows outward and does not return. The amplitude of the wave diminishes as it spreads.

If there are boundaries, the wave can be reflected back toward the center. Such a wave can grow in amplitude until it meets at the center, passes through itself and spreads out again.

In that case you might arrange things so the next drop adds a new ripple in phase with the outgoing reflected ripple. In principle this can build. In practice, there are losses as Bob D says. For example, a wave breaks if it gets too big. But see [Inside The Navy's Indoor Ocean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pir_muTzYM8). With bigger-than-drop sloshes, you can make significant waves.